# Why haven't I received my Electorate badge yet?

Tags: support, badges

The **Electorate** badge is given when a user votes 600 times and 25% of the votes are on questions if I understand correctly.

I reached that couple of months back and while looking at my profile now, I have apparently voted 914 times and *almost* half of them are questions and I still haven't achieved the badge yet. Have I misunderstood the badge-awarding procedure for this badge or is something wrong with the system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interpretation of the electorate badge is incorrect. The user should have voted on 600 *questions* and not just vote 600 times along with the added requirement of at least 25% of the total votes are being voted on questions.

Evidence:

The snippet from the [badges page](https://askubuntu.com/badges):

[image]

The snippet from my [review page](https://askubuntu.com/review/):

[image]

You can [verify](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) that those are the exact number of votes that I have cast on questions.

From your [profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/18887/nitstorm), I note that you have voted on 427 questions and you still have quite a distance to cover before the electorate badge is awarded to you. Good luck!

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up :) Awesome answer :)